# Pytorch dimension change

Tags: pytorch, stack, concatenation, dimension

Is there any methods to change [1,512,1,1] to [1,512,2,2] tensor.
I know it is not possible just by changing the dimensions.
Are there any ways using concat or stack with PyTorch (torch.stack, torch.cat)

I make tensor with following code

```
a = torch.rand([1,512,1,1])
```

How can I change this to tensor with dimension [1,512,2,2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be with [`torch.repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html), this will copy the data:

```
>>> a = a.repeat(1, 1, 2, 2)
```

If you do not wish to copy the data, then use [`torch.expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html#torch.Tensor.expand):

```
>>> a = a.expand(-1, -1, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want.
What is difference between repeat and expand?

Comment: `expand` will make it so the expanded dimensions refer (*references* not *copies*) to the original dimensions, which means the tensor takes the same amount of memory. `repeat` on the other hand will copy the data; In your case, going from `(1, 512, 1, 1)` to `(1, 512, 2, 2)`, makes tensor `a` take 4x as much memory. For example - with `expand` - if you do `a[:, :, 0, 0] = 1`, then `a[:, :, 0, 1]`, `a[:, :, 1, 0]`, and  `a[:, :, 1, 1]` will also be `1`, since they all refer to the same underlying memory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
tmp = torch.cat([a,a],2)
a = torch.cat([tmp,tmp],3)
```